# Frequency cross tabulation with combinations of binary variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(dummyA=c(0,0,1,0,1), dummyB=c(1,1,0,1,1), dummyC=c(0,0,1,1,1))

> df
  dummyA dummyB dummyC
1      0      1      0
2      0      1      0
3      1      0      1
4      0      1      1
5      1      1      1
```

Are there ways to cross-tabulate frequency of all conbinations as illustrated below? I need to tabulate it in matrix format.

[image]

There are two rows with dummyA=1 (row# 3 and 5), thus left-top cell is 2. There is one row (#5) with dymmyA=1 and dmmyB=1, thus left-middle cells is 1. Two rows (#3 and 5) has dymmyA=1 and dymmyC=1, thus left-bottom cell is 2.

There are a lot of posts which deal with cross tabulation in R but I have not found this type of tabulations yet. I prefer `dplyr` for data manipulation but any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(dummyA=c(0,0,1,0,1), dummyB=c(1,1,0,1,1), dummyC=c(0,0,1,1,1))

df
#>   dummyA dummyB dummyC
#> 1      0      1      0
#> 2      0      1      0
#> 3      1      0      1
#> 4      0      1      1
#> 5      1      1      1

m <- as.matrix(df)

crossprod(m, m)
#>        dummyA dummyB dummyC
#> dummyA      2      1      2
#> dummyB      1      4      2
#> dummyC      2      2      3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `crossprod(as.matrix(df))` is even easier, or `crossprod(as.matrix(df)) * lower.tri(diag(ncol(df)), diag = TRUE)` if the OP only wants the lower triangle, as per the question.

Comment: @AllanCameron It is perfect. Thank you, I did not realized `crossprod` function. Both full triangle and lower triangle are welcomed.